# My class, defined in a .h file, is not found by the .cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I am trying to make a program with a class called "Deck". However, I am unable to define the functions outside of the header file.

The header Deck.h file has the following:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>
//#include "Card.h"

class Deck{
public:
   vector<Card>* deck = new vector<Card>;
   bool visibility; //Whether you are allowed to view the deck

   Deck();
   Deck(bool visibility);

   void shuffle();



};



#endif
```

And the Deck.cpp file has the following code:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <vector>
#include "stdafx.h"

Deck::Deck(){
   this.visibilty = false;
}

Deck::Deck(bool visibility){
   this.visibility = visibility;
}

void Deck::shuffle(){
   vector<Card>* shuffleHolder = new vector<Card>;

   shuffleHolder = this.deck;
}
```

For some reason, I always receive the errors:

```
1>Compiling...
1>Deck.cpp
1>.\Deck.cpp(5) : error C2653: 'Deck' : is not a class or namespace name
1>.\Deck.cpp(5) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>.\Deck.cpp(6) : error C2673: 'Deck' : global functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>.\Deck.cpp(6) : error C2228: left of '.visibilty' must have class/struct/union
1>.\Deck.cpp(7) : warning C4508: 'Deck' : function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed
1>.\Deck.cpp(9) : error C2653: 'Deck' : is not a class or namespace name
1>.\Deck.cpp(9) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>.\Deck.cpp(10) : error C2673: 'Deck' : global functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>.\Deck.cpp(10) : error C2228: left of '.visibility' must have class/struct/union
1>.\Deck.cpp(11) : warning C4508: 'Deck' : function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed
1>.\Deck.cpp(13) : error C2653: 'Deck' : is not a class or namespace name
1>.\Deck.cpp(14) : error C2065: 'vector' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Deck.cpp(14) : error C2065: 'Card' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Deck.cpp(14) : error C2065: 'shuffleHolder' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Deck.cpp(14) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'
1>.\Deck.cpp(16) : error C2673: 'shuffle' : global functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>.\Deck.cpp(16) : error C2228: left of '.deck' must have class/struct/union
```

I am trying to figure out what the problem is, otherwise I might have to define all the functions inside of the Deck.h file and get rid of the .cpp file altogether.

Comment: Visual Studio can be pretty picky about the precompiled header, often if it doesn't find it first, it will stop processing `include` statements. Try moving `#include "stdafx.h"` to be the first include in `Deck.cpp`

Comment: Visual C++ will not include header files included above `#include "stdafx"`.

Comment: Do not use new for the vector

Comment: `vector<Card>* shuffleHolder = new vector<Card>;
shuffleHolder = this.deck;`and gone is the new vector.

Comment: Be careful, as it is now, the `shuffle` method has a memory leak: you dynamically allocate a new vector, and you immediately lose the only existing pointer to this object, thus creating a non-reachable memory zone.

Comment: @lcs -- or just get rid of "stdafx.h" entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using precompiled headers `#include "stdafx.h"` must appear before every #include in every file. Otherwise the preprocessor/compiler will ignore the other files. You can read more about how to use precompiled headers [here](https://yxbenj.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/a-quick-guide-to-using-precompiled-headers-visual-studio/). The other option is just not use them if you don't need the improved compilation time.

Some unrelated notes about your code: `this` is *pointer* to the current object, so you cannot access properties from it with the dot `.` operator(which is used for objects with class type, not pointer). You have to use `->`. For example `this->visibility` or if it is unambiguous just `visibility`. Also since you have dynamic memory allocation with `new` you have to have a destructor that calls `delete`. But in this particular case `new` is not needed and you can just let the vector manage the memory itself by making it a vector variable and not a pointer and not defining it with `new`.